# PERT chart javascript library

Tags: library, javascript, charts

I'm going to start a web application that needs to show data using [PERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PERT) charts from a given dataset.

I did a little bit of research of some javascript frameworks that I can use and the possible solutions that I found are:

- [D3.js](https://d3js.org/)
- [Cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/)
- [Sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/)
- [jointjs](http://www.jointjs.com/)
- [GoJS](https://gojs.net)

In your opinion which is the best/most suitable to use? Have you already did such a choice? As a note I can tell you that the application will be developed 
almost certainly using Angular.

Additional requirements:

- The ability to change the content of the nodes dynamically - for example, we want to use them to display numbers, strings, but also charts (line, bar, ...) and images.
- To have draggable nodes with the ability to save their position for future usage.
- It would be nice to have edges that can be modified if they overlap with nodes, i.e. by adding a break point to the edge and dragging with the mouse.
- The library license must allow commercial use
- Free or paid solution (no price limit yet since we are in design stage)

Comment: @Izzy I have edited the question. Do you think I need to move the question to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: No you can't ask for external resources on SO. The question is fine here (now).

Comment: Agreed. As long as you'd also accept if someone comes up with a product you did *not* mention – as we don't do product comparisons here. Hint: phrases like "which is the best X" trigger itchy fingers here, as they indicate "primarily opinion-based" answers. So we read your question now as "which product meets the listed requirements", and everything is fine :) Thanks for the update!

Comment: "In your opinion " .... vote to close

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript/Angular](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram including PERT Charts. Here is an [example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/ibayliem).

[image: PERT chart Syncfusion]

- Change content dynamically: Yes
- Draggable nodes: Yes
- Connectors can be moved and edited
- Commercial use: Yes. See below for details regarding community license also.

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: I got a Syncfusion community license, but the problem is that it only comes to be installed on Windows OS machines.
Don't you plan to develop for Linux systems?